# FPGA reached the limit of USB WireIns

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, spartan

I'm programming a Xilinx Spartan-6 on an OpalKelly implementation for my master thesis at university.
To by precise, this is the FPGA I'm working on (XEM6010-LX45): https://www.opalkelly.com/products/xem6010/

It is mounted on a board that has to acquire multiple signals (8+), process them and generate multiple ones (16+) to close some feedback loops based on the settings.

It is controlled by a User Interface built in C# that I'm also programming myself and that must be able to change the feedback logic used when needed without restarting the experiment. This means that the USB interface continuosly sends data to update the settings.

I've just encountered the classic (I suppose) problem where I've just run out of WireIns, that are the Opal Kelly implementation for the USB transmission of data from the C# program to the FPGA.

They are limited to 16bits data with addresses from 0x00 - 0x1F (so 32 WireIns). More details here page 41 http://assets00.opalkelly.com/library/FrontPanel-UM.pdf

---

Here is the **question**: how can I increase the data I can send to the FPGA?

The first idea that comes in mind is a big **multiplexer** in the FPGA that just uses two WireIns, one for the data, the other as a selector. Then a trigger activates the FPGA, storing the data into the right addressed register.

Is this really viable or it's incredibly **inefficient**? Should I use the **WireORs** (see the FrontPanel manual I linked)? Should I use a **PipeIn** and in some way manage the required multiplexer?

How FPGA designers overcome this USB communication limit?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have lots of data that you can stream, use a Pipe.

If you want to access the data randomly, you'll have to use a multiplexer, controlled by a WireIn.

Regarding efficiency, you'll have to specify what dimension of efficiency you are interested in, and what value is acceptable.  For example, bandwidth, latency, LUTs used.

--- Update with some code

If you have an array of vectors to update called `regs` and 2 wirein signals called `address` and `data` then you just need to do:

```
regs(to_integer(unsigned(address))) <= data when rising_edge(clk);
```

That will be pretty efficient anyway.  If you need to be more careful about glitches on the registers, you might want to use a TriggerIn also, so you can set up the address and data and then trigger the transfer.

```
regs(to_integer(unsigned(address))) <= data when rising_edge(clk) and trigger_signal = '1';
```

If your synthesiser won't accept the code above, you'll have to log a bug and convert it into a clocked process with an `if` statement inside the clocked part.

Comment: I'm not experienced enough to estimate what would be an acceptable dimension mid project. At the moment I'm limited to 32 16bit words but I'll need at least three times that amount, and most of them should be modifiable mid experiment without influencing the other values. I was wondering if there is a proper/optimized way to code such multiplexer

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code, i have a doubt about the trigger signal: why not rising_edge(trigger_signal) since it is a pulse i could use? I have a lot of different clocks in the design: 2, 38, 40, 80Mhz

Comment: Only ever use true clock signals in rising_edge statements.  Its the first rule of synchronous design about which much has been written.  And make sure you use the clock that the trigger is synchronous too (ie the trigger in block's clk port)  If you have lots of different clocks, you need to be very careful moving signals which are driven in one domain to another - search for clock domain crossing

Answer (score 1):

The good response would be to use the okRegisterBridge, but as I can see on your board description, it's only available on USB 3.0 :(

Then yes, in your case if you want to increase your address space you have to do a multiplexer with one okWireIn register for address and one for writedata.

Comment: Apart from needing a laptop with USB 3.0 for the experiments, what are the steps I need to do to switch to USB 3.0 both in VHDL and C#? When i begun to program this board the first firmware version was already coded, so I don't have any experience in initializing the USB communication.

Comment: The problem is from the kit you use : https://www.opalkelly.com/products/xem6010/
It work with USB2.0. And in your [manual](http://assets00.opalkelly.com/library/FrontPanel-UM.pdf) (page 60) I saw that only kit with USB3.0 support okRegisterBridge.